# GSAP + PaperJS position animation

Tags: javascript, gsap, paperjs

I am trying to integrate it into an existing Paper.js application to replace the original .tweenTo function (http://paperjs.org/reference/tween/). The only issue I am facing so far is the "chaining" of the position or point property animations:

https://codepen.io/yevsim/pen/GRmPBZB

```
paper.install(window)  
paper.setup(canvas);

const text = new PointText({
    point: new Point(100, 100),
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 48,
    fillColor: 'black'
});
text.content = 'Move me';

const timeline = gsap.timeline();

timeline.to(text.point, { duration: 1, x: '+=100' });
timeline.to(text.point, { delay: 1, duration: 1, x: '+=100' });
```

For the reason unknown to me, it moves the text back to its original position before doing the second animation (i.e. instead of going from 100 -> 200 -> 300, it goes 100 -> 200 -> 100 -> 200). Chaining other properties animation e.g. width, height, color, opacity works as expected. I tried to play with replacing point with position, combining them together, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I recommend bringing this up in [the GSAP forums](https://greensock.com/forums/) if you haven't already.

Comment: For anybody wondering, looks like `fromTo` (https://greensock.com/docs/v3/GSAP/Timeline/fromTo()) is the way to go here. Now waiting for an answer from the GSAP forums. Will update here.

Comment: Looks like Paper.js returns a different object every time you reference `text.point`. Here is the solution: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/29079-gsap-paperjs-position-animation/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure why but this will work if you store `text.point` into a variable and use this variable instead of a reference to the actual object when creating your timeline.

Based on your code, here a corrected version:

```js
const text = new PointText({
    point: new Point(100, 100),
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 48,
    fillColor: 'black',
    content: 'Move me'
});

// Use a variable to reference the property to animate.
const point = text.point;
const timeline = gsap.timeline();
timeline.to(point, { duration: 1, x: '+=100' });
timeline.to(point, { delay: 1, duration: 1, x: '+=100' });
```